# Jquery onclick event to change to onload

Tags: jquery

I am using following code which works perfeet when i click on  Link1, what i want to do is it should automatically on pageload fire the event loadContent, how to do that ?

```
<head>
<title>jQuery test page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {
$(""+elementSelector+"").load("http://abc.com/"+sourceUrl+"");
}
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:loadContent('#content', 'displayimages.php');">Link 1</a>
<div id="content">content will be loaded here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript events should go in "onclick", not "href". Correct way: <a href="javascript://" onclick="loadContent('#content', 'displayimages.php');">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the method on page load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   loadContent('#content', 'displayimages.php');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Please this in a script tag in your document. The code contained within this block will be executed when the page has fully loaded.

```
$( function() {
    loadContent('#content', 'displayimages.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add loadContent('#content', 'displayimages.php') outside the function within the script tag, so it's called as soon as the page loads. Basically, your script tag will now look like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
// The function call
    loadContent('#content', 'displayimages.php')

// The actual function
    function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {  
    $(""+elementSelector+"").load("http://abc.com/"+sourceUrl+"");  
    }  
    </script>
```

Another option would be to call it on body onload, by changing your body tag to

```
<body onload="loadContent('#content', 'displayimages.php')">.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Obi, good answer but if he is using jQuery there is a supported way of doing things on document ready. You might want to go check out the jquery pages if you are interested in this sort of thing.

Comment: Oh I didn't know he wanted a JQuery solution. I'm familiar with using document.ready, but just didn't think about it.

Comment: Yeah, now you mention it none of the original stuff was jquery based but he did have it in the tags so in fact your answer was probably more appropriate than I first thought. :)